# Qt treewidget sorting top-level items

Tags: qt, sorting, parent-child, qtreewidget

I am having a difficult time overloading `QTreeWidgetItem`'s `<` operator.

I have a list of `QTreeWidgetItems`, some top-level items and some children. When the user activates the "date created" column to sort the tree, the sort occurs at the child level.

In other words, imagine a tree like this:

```
Item A - latest modification 9/24/12
  3rd Modified -             9/21/12
  2nd Modified -             9/15/12
  1st Modified -             9/10/12

Item B - latest modification 9/23/12
  2nd Modified -             9/23/12
  1st Modified -             9/22/12
```

When the date column is activated to sort ascending, I would expect the return result to be: Item A, then Item B... but instead, the sort occurs on the 1st modified date of the item. I am returned with Item B then Item A. Even though none of the top-level items are expanded, or active.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a QWidgetTree to dispay your QTreeWidgetItems list :
You can add your 2 firsts level item (item A and B), sort your QwidgetTree and then add your low level items.
so your tree will be sorted by latest modification